# Regular expression for Jmeter webdriver

Tags: html, regex, jmeter

I'm currently using Jmeter webdriver for performance test on a web application. I'm trying to click on a button on the page, but this is under a few frames. The problem one of the frame, that changes name for every session. This is the HTML code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="iframe3970-45593-1439460248299" tabindex="-1" src="https://grcrep.fiatitem.com/BOE/portal/1508131050/AnalyticalReporting/WebiView.do?bypassLatestInstance=true&amp;cafWebSesInit=true&amp;bttoken=MDAwREcwXFo2V25vZk00QTtoS1xiUko5Y2Y6T11qOzAEQ&amp;bttoken=MDAwREcwXFo2V25vZk00QTtoS1xiUko5Y2Y6T11qOzAEQ&amp;opendocTarget=infoviewOpenDocFrame&amp;appKind=InfoView&amp;service=%2FInfoView%2Fcommon%2FappService.do&amp;loc=en&amp;pvl=en_US&amp;ctx=standalone&amp;actId=3970&amp;objIds=45593&amp;containerId=45589&amp;pref=maxOpageU%3D50%3BmaxOpageUt%3D200%3BmaxOpageC%3D10%3Btz%3DEurope%2FBerlin%3BmUnit%3Dinch%3BshowFilters%3Dtrue%3BsmtpFrom%3Dtrue%3BpromptForUnsavedData%3Dtrue%3B&amp;tidtime=3970-45593-1439460248299" style="width: 1600px; height: 703px;"></iframe>
...
    <iframe id="webiViewFrame" name="webiViewFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="margin:0px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:100%;height:100%" src="webiDHTML/dhtmllib/empty.html"></iframe>
...
       <div id="IconImg_iconMenu_icon__dhtmlLib_268" class="imo" style="width:16px;height:16px;background-image:url('images/main/galleries/icon16x16gallery1b.png');background-position:0px -208px;margin-top:2px;cursor:pointer"></div>
```

I want to click on the button with `id=IconImg_iconMenu_icon__dhtmlLib_268`
that is under the iframe webiViewFrame and the iframe `iframe3970-45593-1439460248299`. This last frame changes name at every session. The only part that is fixed is `iframe3970-`. How can I locate this element. I've tried using regular expression `WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id("iframe3970-"+"([0-9]+?)"))` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not `findElement(By.id("IconImg_iconMenu_icon__dhtmlLib_268"))` Why is parent ID relevant?

Answer (score 2):

Try locate iframe with an id that starts with the text prefix:

```
  WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector("iframe[id^='iframe3970-']"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for